# MS Excell: make a total of all cells in a row minus ones with letters

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am struggling with Microsoft Excell. I am using it to keep track of averages and totals.Example: `ROW 1 7,5,9,4,10,A,D,0,2 Sum:37 AVG 3.9` How can I create a sum of all numbers divided by the total numbers in one row minus the cells where I put alphabets? Is there a way to skip these cells easily? Is there a formula to add up all cells with numbers minus the ones with letters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `=sum(A1:I1)` in `J1` works fine. After that use a `=count(A1:I1)` in `K1` and then just use `=J1/K1` in `L1`

the `=count()` function will only count numbers, not letters

### edit

`=avg(A1:I1)` only averages numbers not letters. What's the problem?

Comment: Or using @Raystafarian notation, in one cell combine both functions as a single formula =count(A1:I1)/count(A1:I1). Also, the average seems to be 5.28, not 3.9. Are we missing something?

Comment: It was way easier than I thought. Thanks for all the tips. As I split the totals and averages and all letter are ignored I was able to add
`=SUM(AM10:BA10)` and `=AVERAGE(AM10:BA10)` I did look into count() as well, but as SUM did the trick as well I am all good.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct

Your input is as below,

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J
1   7   5   9   4   10  A   D   0   2
```

then average of above numbers will be **4.75**

```
=AVERAGE(A1:J1)
```

Here it calculates only numbers.

Below are the list of formulas / scenarios, which gives same result as **"4.75"**

```
=(A1+B1+C1+D1+E1+F1+I1+J1)/COUNT(B1,A1,C1,D1,E1,F1,I1,J1)
=SUM(A1:J1)/COUNT(B1,A1,C1,D1,E1,F1,I1,J1)
=SUM(A1:J1)/COUNT(A1:J1)
```